# How to check if the restart policy works of Docker

Tags: docker, boot2docker

From the Docker [document](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#restart-policies-restart), there is a `restart policy` parameter could be set.

How do I verify the container indeed restarts when the container exits. How to trigger the exit of container manually, and observe if the container restarts?

My environment is Mac and boot2docker.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can also `docker exec -it container_id bash` and then `kill -9` of the main process. I tested with `docker run -d --restart=always -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /home/gg/moncontainer:/home/gg -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix k3ck3c/captvty` I killed the main process (pid 5, Captvty.exe), was logged out of the container, and 2 seconds later it was restarted, the window was created again

Comment: cool, I learn a new command `docker exec -it <container_id> bash` to get into the container shell. 

Thanks, this method works, a little inconvenience is I don't know what process I should kill to cause exit, so I try one by one. Anyway, it restarts indeed :)

Comment: I found the process should be killed is about the process ran in ENTRYPOINT or CMD

Answer (score 25):

After running the container you can inspect its policy, restart coun and last started time:

```
docker inspect -f "{{ .HostConfig.RestartPolicy }}" <container_id>
docker inspect -f "{{ .RestartCount }}" <container_id>
docker inspect -f "{{ .State.StartedAt }}" <container_id>
```

Then you can look into container processes:

```
docker exec -it <container_id> ps -aux
```

The PID 1 process - is the main process, after its death the whole container would die.

Kill it using:

```
docker exec -it <container_id> kill -9 <pid>
```

And after this ensure that the container autorestarted:

```
docker inspect -f "{{ .RestartCount }}" <container_id>
```

Comment: You can also do `docker kill <container_id>` which will send a `SIGKILL` to the container by default.

Answer (score 1):

I just created a container manually, like this:

```
docker run -d --restart=always tacodata/pythondev sleep 10
```

note, that the daemon starts, but the container exits in 10 seconds. Everytime I do a docker ps I see:

```
core@pa2 ~ $ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                     COMMAND             CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
69cbae4b6459        tacodata/pythondev:latest                 "sleep 10"          About a minute ago   Up 9 seconds        5000/tcp                 high_colden
```

So, the container was created a minute ago, but the status shows it up only 9 seconds.  It keeps restarting.  You can get that information from:

```
core@pa2 ~ $ docker inspect high_colden
[{
"AppArmorProfile": "",
...
"Path": "sleep",
"ProcessLabel": "",
"ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/69cbae4b645926b14d86effcfaaa7735119e7f0c8afb0baff5cc1913583bf35a/resolv.conf",
"RestartCount": 16,
"State": {
    "Error": "",
    "ExitCode": 0,
    "FinishedAt": "2015-04-16T16:36:15.325629703Z",
    "OOMKilled": false,
    "Paused": false,
    "Pid": 13453,
    "Restarting": false,
    "Running": true,
    "StartedAt": "2015-04-16T16:36:15.860163812Z"
},
"Volumes": {},
"VolumesRW": {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is also a good solution. But, `sleep` should only trigger the `zero exit status` exit right? Is there other way to trigger `non-zero exit status` exit?

Answer (score 0):

You can also restart docker service to see if it's firing up containers upon start. Under Ubuntu, for example,

```
sudo service docker restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

- Get the Container ID of the container to be killed with `docker ps`.
- Then do `ps -efa | grep <Container ID>` to get the Process ID.
- Then do `sudo kill -9 <Process ID>`.